# Obtaining the direction of flow from principle of increase of entropy?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, reversibility, arrow-of-time

Can we mathematically show that water flows from high-pressure region to low-temperature region and why particles flow from a region of higher chemical potential to lower on the basis of the principle of increase of entropy?

Answer (score 1):

Starting from the chemical potential denfinition:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial S(E,V,N)}{\partial N} = - \frac{\mu(E,V,N)}{T(E,V,N)},  
\end{equation}

For two systems in contact $\mu_1 = \mu_2$ should be satisfied and for same temperatures of the system, the change in entropy until equilibrium will be (certainly positive, since 2nd therm. law):

\begin{equation}
dS = dS_1 + dS_2 = -(\mu_1 - \mu_2)dN_1 > 0,
\end{equation}

with $dN_2 = - dN_1$, since particles do not get lost. Now assume $\mu_2>\mu_1$, then it must be that $dN_1 > 0 $, meaning that particles flow to system 1, where the chemical potential is lower.
Maybe you can find something similar for your pressure and temperature related questions.

Cheers